# C# designer form not updating methods of form objects?

Tags: c#, forms

I've been following [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492140.aspx) tutorial to name the elements on a windows form page. From what I gathered, the form will auto generate methods based on the name of the elements on the designer form.

However, while most of the textboxes, labels do update their method name when I click them and hit ENTER, some of them still reference to the default name.

In the attached image the label named "Option" remains as "label3_clicked".

Much appreciated.

[Attached image of problem.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o62DM.png)

Comment: While generating (registering) the `event` of any `control` VS take `name of that control` + `_ (underscore)` + `event name` in future if you change name of that control windows does not effect `(rename)` already generated event

Comment: Once the event handler (the method, not the control) is created, it is never changed automatically by simply renaming the control: `label3` and `label3_clicked` are completely separate symbols, and you can easily attach the same event handler to multiple controls. But if you manually rename the event handler (`label3_clicked`) inside the file, VS will offer to search for all occurences and rename them. If you want to avoid having to do this, simply make sure you name the control *before* you create the event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You created the click event handler method while the Label was called label3.  To fix this highlight the method name in your code behind and F2.  That will enable you to change (refactor) the name of the method which in turn, will change the form designer as well.

In future just name your objects first and then create your event handler methods and all should be good.

Answer (score 1):

I never experience the behavior where the name of the event (which can be anything) is automatically updated to match the name of the control.

This is because the name of the event can be just anything (`label3.Clicked += Whatever_Click_Whatever` or even without the click Part). There is no naming rules that the compiler can check. There is just the default for auto generated ones.

What if you have a custom name that you don't want to change when changing the control name? So there is no automatic behavior here.

So what you can do is go to `Form1.Designer.cs` find the event like this:

```
this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.Form1_Load);
```

Then `Right click => Rename` or `Ctrl + R, Ctrl + R` and change the name. This changes it is your form's code also.

Answer (score 0):

It is a simple issue. You can fix this by creating a function when form is loaded. **Set the default value for the form object in `Form1_Load()` function to change it on RunTime**. You can get that function from form events. For example, If I want to change the name of the form, then approach is like

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    this.Text = "Initial Text"
}
```

After that, On your event which you want to change the Form Name. For example, I'm taking some function name

```
private void updateFormName_click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    this.Text = "Updated Text"
}
```